# Angular localstorage using directives

Tags: angular, local-storage, angular-directive, eventemitter

I´m trying to use a directive to verify if there is a value in localstorage and then use it for a filter in the same .

this is my directive:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[local]' })
export class KeyCatcherDirective implements OnInit{
ngOnInit(): void {//Al inicializar todo nos va a devolver el idMoneda que le pasamos en el template
    this.onKeydownHandler()

}
    @Input('local') myId:string
    @Output() keydown: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  
    
    onKeydownHandler() {
        console.log(this.myId)
       console.log((localStorage.getItem(this.myId)?localStorage.getItem(this.myId):'there is nothing'))
        this.keydown.emit(localStorage.getItem(this.myId)?localStorage.getItem(this.myId):null)
    }
}
```

My template:

```
<div local="something" (keydown)="parentKeydown($event)"></div>
```

What do i need to do:
When an user enter to this component I have to remember his filters.

If localStorage.getItem(something) exists, use this value. I think it could be in an ngmodel select or something.
¿Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: While I do not get your point based on what you provided above, I think this an over engineering approach. Can you please provide a stackblitz link with full reproduction code in case you this is critical for you

Comment: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-angular-material-reactive-form-b9g6fx?file=app/mydirective.directive.ts) 

I need to make a directive to use it in multiple forms. So, when i use this directive, it has to verify if there is a value selected in localstorage. If so, use this value, if not, return null or something like that so it works normally

Comment: the code you provided in the link is not compatible with OP above. It has a couple of issues. 1- The directive is not registered in the module. 2- The directive is using .get() on localStorage API while the method name is getItem(). I corrected this and I got the value logged onInit. Additionally, your dropdown options do not have a default null/empty value that's why on init you get value 1.